# Javascript как двигать элемент стрелкой?

Tags: javascript

в JS не очень разбираюсь, нужно управлять элементом стрелкой (верх,вниз,влево,вправо). Элемент(изображение) добавлен в canvas через JS, стартовая позиция задана в переменных, xPlane yPlane. Погуглил и попробывал вот так, чет не работает в консоле ошибок нету

```
function draw() {
        ctx.drawImage(plane, xPlane, yPlane, 200, 70);
        requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    }

document.addEventListener("keydown", move);

    function move(e) {
        if (e.keycode == 37) {
            xPlane -= 3;
        }
        if (e.keycode == 38) {
            yPlane -= 3;
        }
        if (e.keycode == 39) {
            xPlane += 3;
        }
        if (e.keycode == 40) {
            yPlane 5= 3;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `yPlane 5= 3;` вот это как минимум должно выдать синтаксическую ошибку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем примере `e.keycode === undefined` потому что у объекта `e` нет такого поля, зато есть `e.keyCode`


Я сделал маленький пример, может он вам поможет разобраться как это работает

```js
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', move);
var square = document.querySelector('.square');

function move(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var left = Number(square.style.left.slice(0, -2));
  var top = Number(square.style.top.slice(0, -2));
  if (e.keyCode == 37) { // Left
    left--;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38) { // Up
    top--;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 39) { // Right
    left++;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) { // Down
    top++;
  }
  square.style.left = left + 'px';
  square.style.top = top + 'px';
}
```

```css
.square {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Замените `yPlane 5= 3;` на `yPlane += 3;`.
2. Используйте `console.log("номер действия");` либо Debugger из Chrome(или другого браузера) DevTools, чтобы отследить на каком месте программа работает, а на каком нет.